# Cordova application XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, cordova

I am trying to make a POST http request from my cordova application, but it is not working (ios or android), I keep receiving httpRequest.status equals to 0 and httpRequest.responseText is empty, and the server is not reached.

There is plenty of information about this, but I cannot make it work. My config.xml is configure like:

```
<access origin="*">
```

I tried as well doing a GET query to google or other known server but is not working either.

This is the code I am using.

```
function alertContents(httpRequest)
{
  if (httpRequest.readyState == 4)
  {
    // Everything is good, the response is received
    if ((httpRequest.status == 200) || (httpRequest.status == 0))
    {
      alert("The response was: "  + httpRequest.status + " - " +  httpRequest.responseText);
    } else {
      alert('There was a problem with the request. ' + httpRequest.status + httpRequest.responseText);
    }
  }
}

function send_with_ajax() {
alert("Pushing data");

  var the_url = 'http://<servier ip>:<port>/service';
  var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

  httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() { alertContents(httpRequest); };

  httpRequest.open("POST", the_url, true);

  httpRequest.send(null);

}
```

Per the information online it should work, anybody knows if I am missing something ?,

thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: How is `send_with_ajax` called?

Comment: It is called once the event "deviceready" received like this:
 var buttonElement = document.getElementById('data_button');
 buttonElement.addEventListener("click", send_with_ajax, false);

Comment: There is your problem. You do not cancel the click event...

Answer (score 0):

Clicking submit buttons or links will cause the page to submit/navigate away. So you need to cancel the click event so that action does not happen.

```
function send_with_ajax(evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Chances are you need to whitelist the domains you want to request using Content Security Policy as specified here: http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

To solve the problem I had to add a meta-tag similar to this one:

```
<!-- This policy allows everything (eg CSS, AJAX, object, frame, media, etc) except that 
* CSS only from the same origin and inline styles,
* scripts only from the same origin and inline styles, and eval()
-->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

and return the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *` header from my server.